# Email is not sending in django after deploy in Cpanel

Tags: django, deployment, smtp, cpanel

I just deploy a Django web app in Cpanel. But SMTP email is not working in Cpanel. It works only on my local machine. I don't have much knowledge about Cpanel.
Here is my code for setting.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my gmail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

Answer (score 0):

solved!! changed EMAIL_HOST_USER to cpnael hosting email.